# Check if sumbited radio button is true - symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, radio-button

Hello i am trying to see (after the from has been sumited) how i can verify that one of the `'choices' => $question->buildAnswerWithValidKey()` is true.

Here is the array from question.

```
Array
(
    [Sonne] => 1
    [Mond] => 
    [Und Sterne] => 
)
```

And i am trying to Validate this after the Form has been sumited.

Here is my `'choices'`function. Which gets the answers, based on the question with the correct key (in this case 1 or 0, true /false)

```
 public function buildAnswerWithValidKey()
    {
        $answers = [];
        $valid = [];
        $answersWithValidKey = [];

        /** @var Answer $answer */
        foreach ($this->getAnswers() as $answer) {
            $answers[] = $answer->getAnswer();
            $valid[] = $answer->getValid();
        }

        //Sets answers as item and valid as key as required by 'choices'
        $answersWithValidKey[] = array_combine($answers, $valid);

        return $answersWithValidKey;
    }
```

This is my Controller. 
Where i am struggeling to validate the radio button.

```
        /** @var Question $question */
        $question = $this->questionRepository->findById(12)[0];

        $options = ['question' => $question];

        $form = $this->createForm(ExamType::class, null, $options);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        }

        return [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ];
```

Here are my other classes that might be Helpfull.

Answer.php - Where the ManyToOne is mapped.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AnswerRepository")
 */
class Answer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $answer;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Question", inversedBy="answers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="question_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $question;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $valid;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getAnswer(): ?string
    {
        return $this->answer;
    }

    public function setAnswer(string $answer): self
    {
        $this->answer = $answer;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getQuestion(): ?Question
    {
        return $this->question;
    }

    public function setQuestion(?Question $question): self
    {
        $this->question = $question;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getValid(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->valid;
    }

    public function setValid(bool $valid): self
    {
        $this->valid = $valid;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And my Question.php - Where i made my `buildAnswerWithValidKey()` function.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\QuestionRepository")
 */
class Question
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $question;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Answer", mappedBy="question")
     */
    private $answers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->answers = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getQuestion(): ?string
    {
        return $this->question;
    }

    public function setQuestion(string $question): self
    {
        $this->question = $question;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Answer[]
     */
    public function getAnswers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->answers;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the Answers
     *
     * @param mixed $answers
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAnswers($answers)
    {
        $this->answers = $answers;
    }

    public function addAnswer(Answer $answer): self
    {
        if (!$this->answers->contains($answer)) {
            $this->answers[] = $answer;
            $answer->setQuestion($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAnswer(Answer $answer): self
    {
        if ($this->answers->contains($answer)) {
            $this->answers->removeElement($answer);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($answer->getQuestion() === $this) {
                $answer->setQuestion(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function buildAnswerWithValidKey()
    {
        $answers = [];
        $valid = [];
        $answersWithValidKey = [];

        /** @var Answer $answer */
        foreach ($this->getAnswers() as $answer) {
            $answers[] = $answer->getAnswer();
            $valid[] = $answer->getValid();
        }

        //Sets answers as item and valid as key as required by 'choices'
        $answersWithValidKey[] = array_combine($answers, $valid);

        return $answersWithValidKey;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Here is my ExamType

```
 <?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Question;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ExamType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        /**
         * @var Question $question
         */
        $question = $options['question'];


        $builder
            ->add(
                //Used to check in the validation
                'question',
                HiddenType::class,
                [
                    'data' => $question->getId()
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'Answers',
                ChoiceType::class,
                [
                    'choices' => $question->buildAnswerWithValidKey(),
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'label' => $question->getQuestion()
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'Evaluate',
                SubmitType::class
            );
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Question::class,
        ]);

        $resolver->setRequired('question');
        $resolver->setAllowedTypes('question', Question::class);


    }
}
```

Basically i just want to return some kind of message if the user selected the correct answer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191819/discussion-on-question-by-learningsymfony-check-if-sumbited-radio-button-is-true).

Comment: I've moved the discussion to chat for now, feel free to collect them and post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to retrieve data from the form, you have to call `$form->getData()` after it has handled the request and checked if it is valid.

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { 
    $answerData = $form->getData();              
    if (!empty($answerData['Answers'] )) { 
          // do something useful
    }  
}
```

however, the form will return data contents according to its buildForm() method, and the data object, it will try to put the contents in, is defined by the `data_class` option in the `FormType`. If the results are to be returned in an array, the `data_class` should be `null`. (So this must be set as well, alternative is an object, that somehow encodes the return)

Comment: Thank you very much again :)